# Unknown error encountered during ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to insert a record in my database using ajax but it is giving me an unknown error.

I'm using ajax with php to insert a record into database send by a user. The user can also insert tags which first are serialized through jQuery function then sent to php request page through ajax. I'm using jQuery UI and jQuery TokenField files to let the user give his input in tags format and once he/she clicks the button the data gets serialized which can be passed on easily.

This is my form and complete JScript file with the function which lets user to give his input in tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
      <form class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Project Title </label>
                <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project's Title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Project Description</label>
                <textarea name="txtDescpt" id="txtDescpt" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project's Description" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <p id="exception"> </p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Project Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                  <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose Project Category</option>
                  <option value="active">Active Project</option>
                  <option value="drafted">Drafted Project</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- Skill input (in tags) -->
            <div class="form-group create-project-select">
                <label>Skill Tags (for e.g. carpenter, mason, blacksmith, etc.)</label>
                <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="create-project-button">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Project" id="btnCreate" name="btnCreate">
            </div>
      </form>

      <!-- Tags data is coming from database (successfully checked) -->
      <?php
        $selectSkills = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM skills");
        $selectSkills->execute();
        $result = $selectSkills->fetchAll();
      ?>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#skill').tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
              source:<?php echo "[";
                $str = "'";
                foreach ($result as $row): echo htmlspecialchars($str).$row['name'].htmlspecialchars($str).","; endforeach;
                echo "],
              delay:100";
              ?>
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
          });
          $("#btnCreate").click(function () {
            var NameReglExp = /^([A-Za-z_\ _\.]{1,255})$/;
            var name = $("#txtName").val();
            var descpt = $("#txtDescpt").val();
            //var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
            var skills = $.trim($('#skill').val());

            var category = $("#category :selected").attr('value');

            if (name.length > 0)
            {
              if (descpt.length > 0)
              {
                if (category != "0")
                {
                  if (skills.length > 0)
                  {
                    if (NameReglExp.test(name) == true)
                    {
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "working.php",
                        data: {"Name":name, "Descpt":descpt, "Category":category, "Skills":skills},
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function(feedback) {
                          swal("", feedback.message, feedback.status);
                        },
                        error: function(feedback) {
                          swal("", feedback.message, feedback.status);
                        }                        
                      });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      swal("", "You are not allowed to enter any special character as a Project Name.", "error", {buttons : false});
                    }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    swal("", "Please enter atleast one skill to proceed.", "error", {buttons : false})
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                  swal("", "Please select a category.", "error", {buttons : false});
                }
              }
              else
              {
                swal("", "Please write a description about your project", "error", {buttons : false});
              }
            }
            else
            {
              swal("", "Please enter a project name.", "error", {buttons : false});
            }
          });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the connection file where database connection is provide:

```
//database_connection.php

session_start();

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***;charset=utf8mb4", "username", "password");
```

This is my mysql db structure image:

[image: This is my mysql db structure image]

This is my php page where the request is send:

```
<?php
//By providing this file I also execute the session_start() function
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/database_connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Descpt']))
{
    try
    {
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $description = $_POST['Descpt'];
        $status = $_POST['Category'];
        $skills = $_POST['Skills'];
        $date = date("d-m-Y");

        //Converting the value into integer to met the requirments of the database field which takes a value for foreign key as an integer
        $custId = intval($_SESSION['Reg_Id']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO projects (cust_id, name, description, skills_required, date_added, status) VALUES ($custId, '$name', '$description', '$skills', '$date', '$status')";
        $command = $connect->prepare($query);
        if ($command->execute())
        {
            echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Project Created Successfully.']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error Occurred.']);
        }
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $exception = $e->getMessage();
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $exception]);
    }
}
?>
```

An error is arising when executing the php request page. The record is not being inserted. To reach the error I tried echoing `json_encode` function back to ajax request but its not helping either. I personally think the error could be due to tags. Also, there is no letter casing or spelling error.

Comment: The params of the $.ajax `error` callback are `(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`. Try alerting the 3rd param to see what the error is.

Comment: Try to see error by `alert(feedback)` and remove `dataType:'JSON'`

Comment: @Rk003. Well thanks, it helped. I think the problem was with that `dataType: 'JSON'`. Just removed that line and everthing went with the wind. Thankyou.

Comment: `dataType: 'JSON'` will convert **received** JSON strings into JavaScript Objects